# How to inspect element if there are multiple elements with same class name and doesn't have resource-id

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-uiautomator

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<hierarchy rotation="0">


-<node bounds="[0,0][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,0][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" resource-id="android:id/content" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.webkit.WebView" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="true" focused="true" focusable="true" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.webkit.WebView" resource-id="" text="Ionic App" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">

<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0"/>


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="1">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,1280]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[0,42][720,80]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">

<node bounds="[631,42][720,80]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="true" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.Button" resource-id="" text="V 3.5" index="0"/>

</node>

<node bounds="[190,105][530,229]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.Image" resource-id="" text="Himalaya Image" index="1"/>

<node bounds="[288,262][432,369]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.Image" resource-id="" text="Leap Image" index="2"/>


-<node bounds="[35,483][687,628]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="3">


-<node bounds="[131,483][589,565]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[131,483][589,565]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[131,483][589,563]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">


-<node bounds="[131,483][589,563]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="0">

<node bounds="[145,504][575,539]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="true" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.EditText" resource-id="" text="" index="0" NAF="true"/>

<node bounds="[131,483][589,565]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="1" NAF="true"/>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>


-<node bounds="[35,596][687,628]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="1">

<node bounds="[224,602][390,628]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="Register" index="0"/>

<node bounds="[388,596][397,628]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text=" " index="1"/>

<node bounds="[393,602][497,628]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="Forgot PIN" index="2"/>

</node>

</node>

<node bounds="[101,745][619,1106]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.widget.Image" resource-id="" text="Lead 2020" index="4"/>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>

<node bounds="[0,42][720,45]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="" text="" index="1"/>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>

</node>

<node bounds="[0,0][720,42]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.talentpace.substk" class="android.view.View" resource-id="android:id/statusBarBackground" text="" index="1"/>

</node>

</hierarchy>
```

Inspected Element. Tried finding element in code by various ways. But nothing is working. Please suggest what should be the xpath for editing the PIN number in app

1. android.view.view class has multiple elements, resource id and text is null.
2. Only 1 element with class android.widget.editText. But that also doesnt work.

Attached the tree which i am trying to write the code for

[UIAutomatorTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZkdk.png)

Below is the xpath which i tried

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.view.View[@index='3']//android.widget.EditText")

Comment: XPath queries xml scripts. To get better help, I would suggest you to also post the xml page source. You can do this by calling `driver.PageSource`. See [this](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/) resource.

Comment: Attached. In this i need to click on element of class android.widget.EditText

Comment: Ideally, you should really try to get some unique resource-ids for your elements. It will make things less complicated. Of course, you would need access to the source code for that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not answering the question but may help if you have access to the source code.
[setContentDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)) method helps to deal with such problems, it has to be defined in XML which helps not only with accessibility but also during any UI testing. Even when you have an ID/text it may be a situation when multiple views have similar text and/or ids

In your case - dividing elements in the XPath should be done with one slash "/"
Here is an example

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.View[3]/android.widget.EditText[0]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XPath expression, you are trying to get all `<android.widget.FrameLayout[1]>` elements. Looking to your xml, the only elements your document has is one `<hierarchy>` and multiple `<node>` elements. That's why you don't get any results.

Assuming you are coding in C#, try something like this:

```
driver.findElementByXPath(@"//node[@class = ""android.widget.EditText""]));
```

- With the @ you tell the compiler to use string literals, so you don't
  need to escape characters.
- `//node` returns all the `<node>` elements
  in the current xml document.
- `[@class = ""android.widget.EditText""]`
  tells your XPath expression you need elements with a class attribute with a value 
  that equals "android.widget.EditText".
- The double quotation is needed
  so Visual Studio recognises "android.widget.EditText" as a string value.

Note that using // isn't a very efficient way of querying the xml. Always try to avoid it and narrow you XPath expression.
A nice XPath examples list \ cheat sheet from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx). It should help you accomplish this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not coding C#. Will the regular expressions work in java coding.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with java, but the syntax for the XPath expression should be roughly the same yes. Looking up how to escape characters in java should get you where you want.

Comment: Tried using //node[@class='android.widget.EditText'] but this doesnt work. :(

Comment: Try `//node[@class='android.widget.EditText']` in a [online XPath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), it works, its the correct XPath expression. Just paste your xml there (make sure its formatted correctly). I can think of 2 possible problems. Your java specific syntax is wrong, or the xml you are applying the expression to does not contain that element. Try checking the pagesource in code before you apply the XPath expression.

Comment: online XPath tester got me the correct answer which i expected. But still its not finding the element in UI. The code gets hanged and i need to manually terminate the code without finding the element each time.

Comment: Ah good to know the XPath expression works. As I understood, this question was about finding a specific element, but the problem you are facing now is that your code hangs, making it impossible to try and find that element.  I suggest you to make a new question for this new problem, if you didn't already.