# Program gets hanged when trying to automate a mobile application

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Below program hangs completely, after trying to find elements. Doesn't look like anything wrong with xpath either. I need to terminate the program manually each time. Is there anything which i need to change in code or should i need to add something?

```
public class Test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
         DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.1.0");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
          capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.talentpace.substk");
          capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.talentpace.substk.MainActivity");

          URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
          AndroidDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(url,capabilities);
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          driver.findElementByXPath("//node[@class='android.widget.EditText']").click();
    }
}
```

Comment: don't close it manually wait for the exception and share it with us.

Comment: Waited for half an hr. No exception received.

Comment: does the application launched successfully or stuck before it...

Comment: Which appium version are you using? try changing ** AUTOMATION_NAME** capability to **uiautomator2**. Can you share your appium server log?

Comment: `app.getAbsolutePath()` where is app defined?

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep, it's bad practice. Use a while loop with a timer instead. In the while condition, you check whatever needed the waiting time and also if the timer exceeded (in your case) 5 seconds. This way, your code will continue executing earlier and you wont block your thread from running.

Comment: @BibinRoy what error are you getting now?

Comment: @suban the issue is resolved once capability changed to uiautomator2. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **AUTOMATION_NAME** in desired capabilites from **Appium** to **uiautomator2**

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have given the wrong xpath

the correct one should look like this

```
//android.widget.EditText[@class='Enter Class name here..']
```

Comment: Not so sure about that, look at his question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530101/how-to-inspect-element-if-there-are-multiple-elements-with-same-class-name-and-d/55536771?noredirect=1#comment97836882_55536771) for the xml pagesource of the app. As you can see, `android.widget.EditText` isn't a element but a class attribute value.